# Mongodb $in failure from added quotes when passing Array of values from a User Search

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dynamic, quotes

I've spent a very long time trying to find an answer, I've checked every proposed answer provided while making this question, so if this has been answered, sorry for wasting your time. I've been programming for 5 years, and have built a Jquery, PHP, Mysql application. Now I'm redoing it all in Vanilla Javascript and MongoDB using a node backend.

The Params are sent from the user and compiled at the server to formulate different search criteria.
The regArray takes the Params.Criteria and makes an array with each name as a RegExp. For a multiple fuzzy search, using Mongodb's aggregate $in. The failure happens because outer quotes are added when passing the output /John/gim, /Jack/gim, /James/gim to [] or any other way I've tried.

The commented out test part works.

What I need: [/John/gim, /Jack/gim, /James/gim] (Hardcoded Array) This return 2 Documents

What I get: ['/John/gim, /Jack/gim, /James/gim'] (Dynamically Coded) This Fails

If anyone can help me get the required result I would be incredibly thankful.

Here is my code, easy to test - no db needed.

```
    const Params = {
      Field: 'FirstName',
      Criteria: 'John Jack James',
      Seek: { On : false, Case: true},
      Tag: { On: false, By: true },
      Or: false, Not: true,
      ByDate: { Range: false, Year: false, Month: false, Day: false },
    }

    let regArray = Params.Criteria.split(' ').map((knit) => new RegExp(knit, 'igm')).join(', ')
    console.log('regArray: ', regArray);
    let findaMatch = ({ $match : { [Params.Field] : { $in : [regArray] } }})
    // let test = [/John/gim, /Jack/gim, /James/gim]
    // let findaMatch = ({ $match : { [Params.Field] : { $in : test } }})
    console.log('findaMatch: ', findaMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to do with `[Params.Field]` needs to be redone. There is nothing in MQL (MongoDB query language) that accepts arrays as keys like that.

Comment: It's only search parameters sent through the API, those are then formulated into Mongodb Aggregation. It is a security risk to do it clientside, and I needed a way to pass a large amount of options, without bombarding the URL.

From the search bar, users will type multiple words, each word will be searched. I could have asked this question without Mongodb, but felt it better to give context. 
`[Params.Field]` = 'FirstName'
Thanks for replying.

Comment: I cannot understand what you *want* to do, but *this* is not anything that MongoDB understands. Passing arrays as keys is bogus/meaningless.

Comment: Let me explain: 
{FirstName : 'something'} Here firstname is literal.
{key : 'something'} Here key is taken literally, instead of parsing FirstName.
{[key] : 'something'} Here key is a variable, not literal by using square brackets

But this has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer by removing .join()

```
      let Result = 'John Jack James'.trim().split(' ')
      var range = []
      for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i ++ ) {
        range.push( new RegExp(Result[i], 'igm') )
      }
```

or

```
    let regArray = Params.Criteria.split(' ').map((knit) => {
      return new RegExp(knit, 'igm')
    })
```

Now I get `[/John/igm, /Jack/igm, /James/igm]`

And NOT `["/John/igm, /Jack/igm, /James/igm"]`

Now it's an Array of Regexp values, instead of a useless string.